# Tomato plant leaves drying disease

Tags: diagnosis, tomatoes

I have recently planted a few tomato plants in pots but looks like something is eating their leaves they are drying. I would like to know how to stop this, which chemical I need to buy and to spray it to stop.

[image: image1]
[image: imave 2]

Comment: Please post new questions for the other problems. They are unrelated to the issue with your tomatoes. Thanks.

Comment: Also, see https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/9605/what-are-these-white-streaks-on-my-tomato-plant and the other questions linked to it in the sidebar, and let us know if those solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leaf miner, very common as the leaves get older and have to be removed from the bottom upwards the problem will solve itself- plants are annual anyway so shouldn't continue next year if you throw out your compost every year and start again new and sterilised soil for next year.